# Can we make this site a little more flexible in their close reasons?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I asked this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/sharepoint-admin-and-developer-roles) that was closed as **not constructive**.

While this question may not fit in the narrow guidelines of what this community is looking for it is definitely not **not constructive**.

An alternative exists for StackOverflow for these types of general discussion questions, like Code Review, but these more specialty focused sites do not have that alternative.

Can we make this site a little more flexible in it's guidelines and allow these constructive yet discussion oriented questions a little leeway especially considering the amount of traffic they receive.

Can we vote to remove the close reason "not constructive" from this site?

Answer (score 2):

I totally back up the closing of this question.
The Q/A format of the stack exchange sites does not work well with discussion style questions.
Sometimes we allow the Q but make it Community Wiki, but it is really better to use our chat forum, or maybe twitter!

Non consteuctive sound a bit harsh, we do not control the wording of the close Q reasons, but this is definately the best fit of the ones we have.